# Is it possible to log php script execution time server-wide?

Tags: php, time, execution

Is there a way to log execution time of any php scripts running on a webserver? The server is setup similar to a shared hosting setup, except that our customers don't control their hosting or websites. I'm hoping for a way I can use either the apache logs, or perhaps something in php.ini that I can use to track unusually long running scripts without writing some code and inserting it into the footers of 225+ websites.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://code.google.com/p/mod-log-firstbyte/
This will add the %F option which you can add to your Apache access.log configuration.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed. Now, I thought php could start outputting before the script finishes...or does apache only start output until php finishes?

Comment: It starts only when PHP is done.
Try it out:
<?php echo "x"; sleep(5); echo "y"; ?>